# JsonTypeCoercionException: Only objects with default constructors can be deserialize

Tags: c#, mono, unity-game-engine

I'm working with JsonFx using C# (via Mono in Unity3D) to serialize some data but I get: "JsonTypeCoercionException: Only objects with default constructors can be deserialized. (Level[])" when I try to deserialize the data.

I've tried adding a default constructor to the serialized class but I still get the error. Fwiw, I tried the different suggestions in a similar thread: 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/117256-C-deserialize-JSON-array

Here's my code:

```
//C#
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using JsonFx.Json;
using System.IO;

public class LoadLevel : MonoBehaviour {


string _levelFile = "levels.json"; 
Level[] _levels; 

void Start () {

    if (!File.Exists (_levelFile)){

        // write an example entry so we have somethng to read
        StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(_levelFile);

        Level firstLevel = new Level();
        firstLevel.LevelName = "First Level";               
        firstLevel.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


        sw.Write(JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter.Serialize(firstLevel)); 
        sw.Close();

    }


    // Load our levels
    if(File.Exists(_levelFile)){

        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(_levelFile);

        _levels = JsonReader.Deserialize<Level[]>(sr.ReadToEnd());

    }

}
}
```

And here's the object it's serializing:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System; 

public class Level {

public string Id;
public string LevelName;

public Level() {}

}
```

Any ideas? I've tried both with and without the Level() constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your JSON stream actually needs to contain an array for this to work - it can't just be a single element since you're asking for an array in Deserialize.

Comment: That wasn't it exactly but you got me on the right path...my JSON was wonky. I ran it through jsonlint.com and adjusted accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the Serializable attribute.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Level 
 {
     public string Id;
     public string LevelName;
 }
```

Your json array of levels must then look like this:

```
{
  [
    { 
      "Id" : "1",
      "LevelName" : "first level"
    },
    { 
      "Id" : "2",
      "LevelName" : "second level"
    }
  ]
}
```